# When the Internet drops, I can not access the router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I have a modem connected to a router in bridge like this:

[image]

When there is an Internet connection, I can access the router normally.

However, when the connection drops, I cannot access the router by its IP.

My connection is limited. I am using a TP-Link router.

Has anyone ever experienced this?

Comment: Is the modem or the router responsible for doing DHCP? if the modem is doing DHCP and it goes offline, your pc will lose its ip address, and thus it won't be able to connect to the router.

Comment: @LPChip is the router responsible.

Answer (score 0):

Ask this. How are you determining that the internet is dropped?

1) Your symptoms are exactly the same as a WiFi loss, without WiFi you have no access to the router.

2) The same applies if your laptop jumps over to another AP, another network. Not being on the same network you will not see the router. Has your IP address changed?

3) (finally) I would hope you are using a private address for this, not the internet (or WAN) address.

4) Typically not only should you be able to access the router, but also the modem (upstream network). Even if the modem cannot connect.

e.g.   laptop 192.168.0.120 --> router 192.168.0.1 -/-> modem 192.168.100.1

These are example class C ip addresses.

After three years I am posting this answer for the "searchers".

Answer (score -1):

Use wired line to connect to your router with your laptop, and then try again.

Because you do not make it clear that if the connection between router and internet drops or the wireless connection drops, I cannot give you a simple answer.

If the internet drop make it unavailable to get access to your router, maybe there are some bugs on your router, reset it and try again. If it not work, curse TPLINK and buy a new router.

If the wireless drop make your laptop unreachable to your router, use the wired connection and try again. And remember to make the wireless setting on your router correct. If it not work again, curse TPLINK and buy a new router.

Finally, cherish your life,stay away from TPLINK SOHO products.

Finally, if your laptop is ThinkPad with a wireless adapter called rtl8192ee, double luck!